# How can I get the contents of an array out of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which looks like this when I log it:

```
console.log(msg)
["The Email must be at least 10 characters long."]
```

I thought this meant that the text is inside an array as the 1st and only element. However 
when I try to get the first element it gives me:

```
console.log(msg.[0]))
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

How can I extract the text from the msg variable?

Comment: If `msg` is an array with a single element, you would say `msg[0]` to retrieve that element.

Comment: Try `console.log(msg[0])`

Comment: Not sure why downvoted... It's a syntax error, not an intended one.

Comment: People down vote for no apparent reason on stackoverflow.

Comment: @EricWu, it's being downvoted and voted to close because it's a simple typo. A simple google search for [documentation on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is enough to see the issue.

Comment: Can't argue with that... But it's been agreed somewhere that RTFM comments and actions are not needed; It's a mistake, and quite a common/annoying one within the javascript starters (says the one who wasted two years cursing the js creators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're syntax is wrong, instead you need:

```
console.log(msg[0]))
```

`[]` accessors are used for array access, or to access an object property via a string `myObj["value"]`

`.` accessors are used for fields when you know the name so you could use `myObj.value`

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I was getting confused between objects and arrays.

Comment: Psst! Upvoting and approving the answer will instantaneously kill a still-not-unearthed zombie  ;D

Comment: ... ... ... Never mind, @Ian.  Bad joke.

Answer (score 3):

**To get the contents of an array:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
     console.log(yourArray[i]);

}
```

**To get the contents of an object:**

```
for (var obj in myObject) {
   console.log(obj);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply remove the `.` when accessing individual array elements.

therefore it becomes :

```
console.log(msg[0]);
```

Comment: @EricWu but yours has a syntax error.

Comment: Mea culpa. `Console` is ASP.NET's. :\
'Tis the hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Take the dot in `msg.[0]` out.

```
console.log(msg[0])
```

should retrieve your text correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @olly_uk. I've been using too much ASP.Net's Console recently xD

Comment: no problems, got the privilege so might as well use it :-)